# Is 'parenthesis' singular in this utterance, is it correct to introduce it with the article 'a'?

Tags: grammatical-number, indefinite-articles, parentheses

**Which is correct, introducing *parenthesis* with *a* ...**

Which three types of punctuation can be used to separate **a** parenthesis from the rest of the sentence?

```
                                    OR
```

**omitting the article, as:**

Which three types of punctuation can be used to separate parenthesis from the rest of the sentence?

Comment: That may well depend on what you mean. For example, it seems to me that you might mean a single chatacter: ( or ), or that you might mean a piece of text inside a set of parentheses. I think this needs to be specified if this is to remain an open question. As is, I vote to close for lack of context/detail/clarity.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean here.

Comment: Ok. The question is asking about separating something from the rest of a sentence. Do you mean one of these marks: ( or ) ? If so, you can call it a paren, it means a rounded brace or bracket.

Comment: You can also use parenthesis. If you are talking about both brackets and the text inside them, you can also use parenthesis. So consider: *Sam (who was sick) didn't come.* Do you mean "separate *)* from the part of the sentence that follows it", or do you mean "separate *(who was sick)* from the rest of the sentence"?

Comment: My enquiry was into the use of the word 'parenthesis'. Is it a singular noun that requires the determiner 'a' before it?

If you look at the two sentences I gave, one has the determiner 'a' in bold.

Comment: Ok. Got it. That can be determined by looking up the word in a dictionary. I just Googled *define parenthesis* and found multiple examples with it being introduced with *a*. It should be general knowledge that dictionaries can tell us if a word is a noun, spell its plural form, and note irregularities with regard to forms of number. The question should be closed. It can be answered by consulting a dictionary. See our help section for details about this. Cheers.

Comment: As you wish . . .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"Parenthesis" is singular.  The plural is "parenthes**e**s."  So the "obvious" answer is that you should write "a parenthesis" or "__  parentheses," but not "a parentheses" or "__ parenthesis."

However, [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parenthesis) has multiple attested examples of using "parenthesis" to refer to the *pair* of round brackets as a singular unit (usually in the phrase "in parenthesis").  So I would interpret these as valid:

- "...separate **a** parenthes**i**s..."
- "...separate **a pair of** parenthes**e**s..."
- "...separate parenthes**e**s..."
- ? "...separate parenthes**i**s..." (may need a determiner, or might be acceptable without as in "in parenthesis")

And these as wrong:

- * "...separate **a** parenthes**e**s..." (uses "a" for plural)
- * "...separate **a pair of** parenthes**i**s..." (need a plural after "pair of")

Comment: Thank you for this detailed response!

Using the term 'parentheses' to refer to round brackets seems to be an American thing, as far as I can tell.

You've given me the confidence to go with:

Which three types of punctuation can be used to separate a parenthesis from the rest of the sentence?